# How to get child node names from Parent from firebase database android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my database I have open parent node named "Region".
In that I have children nodes: east, west, south, north. And each child node contains data..
I want to display these nodes names in a text view using an adapter.

After coding it this way, I get the the names repeatedly.. But what I want to do it that, if for example: "west" is already in the parent Node, I want to retrieve only one value of "west"

Is there any way to do that ?
Thanks

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String vid = votersList.get(position).getIdCard();
        final String idCard = votersList.get(position).getIdCard();
        final String region = votersList.get(position).getRegion();

        holder.regionName.setText(region);



private void LoadRegions() {
        voterRef.orderByChild("region").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                votersList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){

                    modelVoters model = ds.getValue(modelVoters.class);
                    if (!model.getRegion().equals("region")){
                    votersList.add(model);
                    adapterRegions = new RegionsAdapter(getActivity(), votersList);

                    //set properties

                    VotersRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRegions);
                    }
                }

            }
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8rsU.jpg)

Comment: Whenever you get the Root node .. you will get a `Map` for regions . Now the Keys of map will points the names you indicated in picture .

Comment: you can get parent node name with String parentNodeName = dataSnapshot.getKey()

Comment: But, dataSnapshot.getKey() returns only the last entered value muiltiple times.